# Should I give a copy of my thesis to those professors that supported me?

Tags: thesis, etiquette

I have just received my master's degree. And I am wondering, is it academically conventional to give a copy of my thesis to those professors that directly or indirectly supported me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is nice to do so (especially if you mention their support in the acknowledgement - which may even be the only things they'll read), but it is far from required.

Comment: Thanks so much. What if I give one to a professor whom I do not mention in the acknowledgment?

Comment: @Chou You can't go wrong by sending a thank-you note and an *offer* of a copy (a physical copy may not be appreciated, per EnergyNumbers' answer)

Comment: @jakebeal: Ah, much appreciated. I see. :)

Answer (score 9):

It can be a nice thing to do: but do ask them first whether they'd prefer to receive an electronic copy, or a bound hard copy, or both.

Not everyone will appreciate a physical copy (seeing it as wasteful or just more clutter): some will prefer a PDF of it; some might prefer both formats.

Comment: If the electronic copy is publicly available on the university website, sending the file by e-mail might come across as a bit ... redundant.

Comment: Sending a link via email, though, may be a nice personal touch.